# Forward declaration of struct with constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, forward-declaration

I would like to add global instances of a struct class to my program that server special meaning. A MWE that works is

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

constexpr int x_max = 3;
constexpr int y_max = 4;

typedef struct Position {

    constexpr Position(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};

    int x;
    int y;

    inline bool operator!=(const Position &rhs) const {
        return (x != rhs.x || y != rhs.y);
    }

    inline bool inside_grid(const Position &empty) const {
        return (x >= 0 && x < x_max && y >= 0 && y < y_max && *this != empty);
    }

} Position;

constexpr Position empty = Position(1,1);


int main()
{
  Position p1 = Position(2,3);
  Position p2 = Position(1,1);

  std::cout << "p1.inside_grid(empty) = " <<  p1.inside_grid(empty) << " and  p2.inside_grid(empty) = " << p2.inside_grid(empty) << std::endl;
}
```

The global constant `empty` would have to be passed to every call of method `inside_grid` which made me think if I could declare the global at the beginning of the program and modify the `inside_grid` method to not take any parameters like so:

```
 // Example program
#include <iostream>

struct Position;

constexpr Position empty = Point(1, 1);
constexpr int x_max = 3;
constexpr int y_max = 4;

typedef struct Position {

    constexpr Position(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};

    int x;
    int y;

    inline bool operator!=(const Position &rhs) const {
        return (x != rhs.x || y != rhs.y);
    }

    inline bool inside_grid() const {
        return (x >= 0 && x < x_max && y >= 0 && y < y_max && *this != empty);
    }

} Position;


int main()
{
  Position p1 = Position(2,3);
  Position p2 = Position(1,1);

  std::cout << "p1.inside_grid() = " <<  p1.inside_grid() << " and  p2.inside_grid() = " << p2.inside_grid() << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that this won't compile due to errors that I cannot really understand:

`error: variable 'constexpr const Position empty' has initializer but incomplete type
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Position'`

Can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You can forward declare your `inside_grid()` method and define it later, after `empty` is created:

```
 // Example program
#include <iostream>

struct Position;

constexpr int x_max = 3;
constexpr int y_max = 4;

typedef struct Position {

    constexpr Position(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};

    int x;
    int y;

    inline bool operator!=(const Position &rhs) const {
        return (x != rhs.x || y != rhs.y);
    }

    bool inside_grid() const;

} Position;

constexpr Position empty = Position(1, 1);

inline bool Position::inside_grid() const {
    return (x >= 0 && x < x_max && y >= 0 && y < y_max && *this != empty);
}


int main()
{
  Position p1 = Position(2,3);
  Position p2 = Position(1,1);

  std::cout << "p1.inside_grid() = " <<  p1.inside_grid() << " and  p2.inside_grid() = " << p2.inside_grid() << std::endl;
}
```